# dbml changes the type of varbinay(max) on Sql Server to Systm.Data.Linq.Binary but not byte[]

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have some table in Sql Server which has `VarBinary(MAX)` and I want to upload files to them, I need to make the Dbml to make the field `byte[]` but instead I get `Systm.Data.Linq.Binary`.

Why is that and how to make the default as `byte[]`? Thanks.

I read the file in my MVC 3 coroller action like this (`resourceFile` is a `HttpPostedFileBase` and `newFile` has the byte[])

```
newFile.FileContent = new byte[resourceFile.ContentLength];
resourceFile.InputStream.Read(newFile.FileContent, 0, resourceFile.ContentLength);
```

Comment: Why do you want to make the property type as of `byte[]`?

Comment: because in my action of MVC project I need to read the file uploaded by ajax and insert it to DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Linq.Data.Binary` type is a wrapper for a byte array that makes the wrapped byte array immutable. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.binary.aspx) page.

Sample code to illustrate immutability:

```
byte[] goesIn = new byte[] { 0xff };
byte[] comesOut1 = null;
byte[] comesOut2 = null;
byte[] comesOut3 = null;

System.Data.Linq.Binary theBinary = goesIn;

comesOut1 = theBinary.ToArray();
comesOut1[0] = 0xfe;

comesOut2 = theBinary.ToArray();

theBinary = comesOut1;

comesOut3 = theBinary.ToArray();
```

The immutability can be seen after changing the value of the first byte in `comesOut1`. The byte[] wrapped in `theBinary` is not changed. Only after you assign the whole byte[] to `theBinary` does it change.

Anyway for your purpose you can use the `Binary` field. To assign a new value to it do as **Dennis** wrote in his answer. To get the byte array out of it, use the `.ToArray()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Binary` to store `byte[]` as well, because `Binary` has [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.binary.op_implicit.aspx) from `byte[]`:

```
myEntity.MyBinaryProperty = File.ReadAllBytes("foo.txt");
```

Comment: thanks, but I edited the question, and from what class `File` was instantiated?

Comment: `System.IO.File` is a static class, the code is just a sample. In your case line will look like `myEntity.MyBinaryProperty = newFile.FileContent`.